# Terminology for a certain generalization of central extensions of Lie algebras

Tags: terminology, lie-algebras

I’m currently reviewing some Lie algebra theory, in particular extension of Lie algebras.
I’m searching for the name of a certain class of extensions, which generalize central extensions.

Let $\mathfrak{h}$ and $I$ be two Lie algebras.
An extension of $\mathfrak{h}$ by $I$ is a short exact sequence
$$
  0
  \to
  I
  \xrightarrow{\;\iota\;}
  \mathfrak{g}
  \xrightarrow{\;\pi\;}
  \mathfrak{h}
  \to
  0
$$
of Lie algebras, i.e. a short exact sequence of vector spaces in which each term is a Lie algebra, and were each map is a homomorphism of Lie algebras.
Up to equivalence of extensions we may assume that
$$
  \mathfrak{g} =  \mathfrak{h} \oplus I
$$
on the level of vector spaces, that $\iota$ is the canonical inclusion and that $\pi$ is the canonical projection.
The Lie bracket of $\mathfrak{g}$ is then of the form
$$
  [(x,c), (y,d)]
  =
  ( [x,y], \kappa(x,y) + \theta(x)(d) - \theta(y)(c) + [c,d] )
$$
for a unique bilinear map $\kappa \colon \mathfrak{h} \times \mathfrak{h} \to I$ and a unique linear map $\theta \colon \mathfrak{h} \to \operatorname{Der}(I)$.

> How are those extensions called which arise – up to equivalence – in the case of $\theta = 0$?

If we would also require the Lie algebra $I$ to be abelian then these would be precisely the central extensions of $\mathfrak{h}$ by $I$.
Here I’m wondering about the case in which $I$ isn’t required to be abelian.

> Moreover, how can these extensions be described without referring to $\kappa$ and $\theta$?

What I have in mind is again the special case of central extension.
These can on the one hand be described in terms of $\kappa$ and $\theta$:
the Lie algebra $I$ must be abelian, and $\theta = 0$.
But they can also be described more intrinsically:
the image of $I$ in $\mathfrak{g}$ must be contained in the center of $\mathfrak{g}$.